# How to convert string filed to list field in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a simple django model

models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_field
```

serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import MyModel

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Using generic view I list all of items

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import MySerializer
from .models import MyModel

class TestView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('test\', views.Test.as_view()),
]
```

And I got following json output:

```
[
   {
    "id":1,
    "my_field":"a,b,c"
   },

   {
    "id":2,
    "my_field":"a"
   },

   {
    "id":3,
    "my_field":"b,c"
   }
]
```

Now I want to convert my_filed values from string to comma-separated list, expected output:

```
[
   {
    "id":1,
    "my_field":["a", "b", "c"]
   },

   {
    "id":2,
    "my_field": ["a"]
   },

   {
    "id":3,
    "my_field":["b", "c"]
   }
]
```

I tried to modify MySerializer as below:

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import MyModel

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.fields['my_field'].split(',')
```

but I got AttributeError: CharField object has no attribute 'split'.

Do you have any ideas how to get expected output?

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: You can not split a field, only the *value* of a field.

Comment: Make sense, but how my serilizer code should looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to split the *field*, not the value for that field. You can write a custom field wrapper based on the `ListField`:

```
from rest_framework.fields import ListField


class CommaSeparatedField(ListField):
    def get_value(self, dictionary):
        value = super().get_value(dictionary)
        return value and value.split(',')

    def to_representation(self, data):
        return ','.join(super().to_representation(data))
```

It might require some extra tweaking, but that is essentially how we can wrap and unwrap items into lists; or comma-separated sequences.

then we can work with:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_field = CommaSeparatedField(serializers.CharField())

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

beware however that comma separated values can be a problem, if the values itself contain commas.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution - 1

#### serializers.py

go with **`serializer.SerializerMethodField()`**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sliped_fields = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id','my_field','sliped_fields']

    def get_sliped_fields(self, obj):
        f_list =obj.my_field.split(',')
        return f_list
```

### Solution - 2 (recommended)

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['my_field'] = instance.my_field.split(',')
        return representation
```

#### admin panel

[image]

#### Response

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "my_field": [
            "g",
            "f"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "my_field": [
            "x",
            "y",
            "z"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "my_field": [
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "my_field": [
            "p",
            "q",
            "r"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "my_field": [
            "hello",
            "how are you",
            "??"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please *don't*: the `SerializerMethodField` works *one-way*: so here to *serialize*, it can not work in the opposite way: to *deserialize*, and this thus nullifies one of the aims of a serializer.